# Should we try to answer questions about specific flights or videos?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9745/how-many-miles-should-an-airliner-put-the-gear-down-before-runway-fedex-flight) asks for information about gear extension on a landing shown in a Youtube video. We already have a *general* [question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/3679/65) about lowering the gear and the new one covers essentially the same ground but for one specific flight. Should we allow/encourage these questions, with the risk that we open up a series of "yes, but what about *this* flight?" questions?

I have a general feeling that we shouldn't encourage questions that amount to speculation/comments on Youtube videos or news reports, but on the other hand the OP's interest is genuine and the question is reasonably clear.

There may be no good answer here and perhaps none is needed if we deal with things on a case-by-case basis anyway, but I thought it might be useful to see if people already have any opinions on this.

Comment: One gauge of these types of question may be "If the video gets taken down, can the question stand on its own?" ... if not, it might not belong on Aviation.SE.

Answer (score 7):

In my opinion only a case-by-case policy should be appropriate. Outright bans will not work - think of incidents like MH370 - questions will pour in, and in some cases we had great answers on the details of satellite communication.

And then there are questions of poor quality, but this is not specific to questions about specific flights or videos. Any topic can generate a bad question, so outright bans of one topic will not help much to avoid them.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with you on this:

> ... we shouldn't encourage questions ...

Generally speaking, there people ask questions about :

- techniques
- incidents

IMHO, we should encourage people to ask specific questions about incidents *as long as* they have searched and then read/acknowledged/referenced that their question is in addition to the technique question which has been already asked and answered on this site. This will show that duplicate questions will not be asked.

Answer (score 1):

The only one asking such question is me, I was searching for a platform to also ask for professional opinion on videos. Because the comments in YouTube aren't professional as we know.
[This One for example is a excellent positive!](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9479/boeing-777-300-strange-windshear-landing) [Or this one!](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9735/orange-object-on-back-of-jet-engine-pylons-what-is-it)

Comment: Yes, the comments are Youtube are often unreliable! I think questions about videos are fine, but I really wanted to see what people think about questions on *specific* cases where we already have a *general* answer. BTW, you should probably edit that question now: the question title and content now have very little to do with the answer that you accepted, so it's a bit confusing.

Comment: Yes Pondlife, you are right, I recognized also that my question quality varies. I think I will probably even delete this stated question.

Comment: I think the KAL landing video in particular was an example of a good question. DeltaLima's answer was also great.

Comment: I'd also point out that sometimes the person asking the question (by virtue of not knowing the answer) doesn't actually know that they're asking a duplicate question. As such, it's up to the community to flag the question up as such and direct the asker to the existing question.